# Spring data elasticsearch - in on string list returns no result, integer works fine

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

So I have a simple document:

```
public class MyDocument {
    @Id
    private String code;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String label;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private Integer catNumber;
    ...
}
```

Now when I do

```
    var labels = List.of("label1", "label2");
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    if (null != labels && !labels.isEmpty()) {
        criteria.and(new Criteria("label").in(labels));
    }

    var query = new CriteriaQuery(criteria);
    query.setPageable(pageable);
    var result = template.search(query, InstallatieDocument.class, IndexCoordinates.of("mydocument"));

    SearchPage<InstallatieDocument> page = SearchHitSupport.searchPageFor(result, query.getPageable());
    return (Page<InstallatieDocument>) SearchHitSupport.unwrapSearchHits(page);
```

I get no results back, if I do: `criteria.and(new Criteria("label").is("label1"));`
I get my expected result back (well part of it).

The strange thing to me is that using in works fine for `catNumber`.

Comment: What's your mapping for the topic ?

Comment: The mapping's done through the annotations on MyDocument.

Answer (score 0):

I just put this code in my sample application (using the current version of Spring Data Elasticsearch) and I see no problems, the query returns the correct data.

Did you make sure, the the mapping in the index is correct for the keyword?

Comment: It looked in order yes.